How can I specify end-of-input using the terminal built into pycharm or VS Code?
I am trying to take all the input at once for competitive programming. The best way I found was the sys.stdin (I am coding in python).
This method works fine when I submit the code to the online judge. But the problem is when I am trying to use it on my code editor (PyCharm/VSCode). After I run the program, The input field is continuously taking input and I can not identify where to stop taking input.
I am sharing a simplified code to show the attempts I make.
import sys

data = sys.stdin.read()
print(data)

I run this code and it never stop taking input so I tried another approach which was taking input from file. I created a input.txt file and enter the all input at once. Next, I run the program with command prompt.
python sample_program.py < input.txt

The command was not working on powershell because < is reserved for powershell but it's worked fine in command prompt
Now, I want to know is there any way to setup my code editor or by changing code to direct run the program and input all at once without need of an external file?

python has a great "batteries included" module to make reading from files and STDIN pretty easy called fileinput  To end the input when reading from STDIN you need an EOF terminator (Ctrl-D on linux)

This isn't really a Python question -- you'd have the exact same problem running any command-line tool that reads input from stdin, including tools that aren't written in Python at all. For example, run wc -l in your shell, and you have the same need to use ctrl+d or otherwise send an EOF when input is complete, no Python involved anywhere.

I don't use PyCharm myself, but is this what you're looking for? Send EOF to PyCharm console in Windows

For VSCode, does this answer your question? How to simulate an EOF? Ctrl+D works for me, but I'm using a different setup.

BTW, for PowerShell, this looks useful: Redirecting standard input\output in Windows PowerShell

Thanks for the informations you provided. ctrl + D is working to stop taking input on pycharm and for vs code ctrl+z following enter. But the problem I am facing now that the entered inputs are not available on my program but other instructions are executed properly. @wjandrea

Two different problems, then -- sounds like the issue you asked about is addressed by the comments above (and the duplicate questions they propose); if you have a new/different issue, we'd want a [mre] that shows us exactly how to produce it ourselves and how to determine what it is ("not available" can mean different things).

That said, if you use the same (ctrl+d or ctrl+z) approach with wc -l, does it output the number of lines you typed before the EOF? (On UNIXy systems, ctrl+z does something else entirely by convention; it'd be good to verify that it genuinely is having the intended behavior here).
